# How can I access semantic ui react theme variables?

Tags: less, semantic-ui-react

I've managed to set my own theme variables using less and create react app.
Now is there a way of accessing these variables for custom components?
For example in CSS-in-JS I'd like to set the background color of a component to @primary. How do I accomplish that?